# What is Partition resolver in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am new to terms used for server farms setup. There is an attribute called partitionResolverType. 
Can someone please explain in easy words what is this partition resolver in the SQL server out-of-proc session state setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify what kind of session state you want to use, [as described here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/23/ASPNET-Session-State-Partitioning.aspx).

If you are using either OutOfProcSessionStateStore (another machine) or SqlSessionStateStore, you may want to change the target machine or Sql server connection at runtime. For example, you may have three machines or Sql servers that you use as backing stores in order to reduce the load on session management.

You can write your own class (custom PartitionResolverType) that ASP will call at runtime to ask for either an IP address or Sql connection string. Your class implements the ResolvePartition(object key) method and returns a string, which is the IP address or Sql connection string of your session store.

You [can find a good example here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/23/ASPNET-Session-State-Partitioning.aspx).